# Every mathematician has only a few tricks

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list, big-picture, gm.general-mathematics

In Gian-Carlo Rota's *["Ten lessons I wish I had been taught"](https://www.ams.org/notices/199701/comm-rota.pdf)* he has a section, *"Every mathematician has only a few tricks"*, where he asserts that even mathematicians like Hilbert have only a few tricks which they use over and over again.

Assuming Rota is correct, what are the few tricks that mathematicians use repeatedly?

Comment: A mathematician never reveals their tricks.

Comment: Going to MO, because that way all the tricks are pooled.

Comment: Tangentially related: [What do named "tricks" share?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48248/6094).

Comment: Polycamelism (thanks Pietro Majer). See https://mathoverflow.net/a/349456 for more.  Gerhard "Called Trick For A Reason" Paseman, 2020.06.15.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't remember the details. In grad school my office mate told me a story about a famous(?) mathematician who would try the same trick (in their head) on every problem they heard, and then only say anything out loud if it worked. Even if it only worked 1/100 times, they still came off looking like a genius. Maybe someone else has heard this and knows the mathematician and/or the trick. (Or maybe it's apocryphal.)

Comment: That story sounds like it might be Feynmann.

Comment: See "Use the Feynman Method" from "Ten Lessons I Wish I Had Been Taught"!

Comment: *embarrassed emoji*

Comment: Just to clarify, what is expected in an answer. Do you expect something along the lines: "Erdős used variations and generalizations of the following tricks in many of his works. 1. ... 2. .... 3. ..." I.e., should the answer contain the name of some mathematician and then some of their trick? Or is this question asking simply for collection of tricks? (If it's the latter, probably we should not bother too much with checking which mathematicians has a particular trick in his bag of tricks.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak If you can attach a mathematician to the trick that would be great but not essential especially as I suspect some tricks are common to many. Ones that you personally use or have learnt from other mathematicians would be interesting.

Comment: Your question has a slightly negative spin to it: it is probably unarguable that any given Mathematician has a finite supply of genuinely new and innovative ideas, but it may be that in some cases, people later realised that ideas they have had earlier in their career are applicable in contexts they had not originally foreseen

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Agreed and also Mathematical ideas I think may often be distinct from tricks which paradoxically could be much more broadly useful. For example "linearity of expectation" is a very powerful trick to use in many different scenarios but as a mathematical idea it's quite basic. Erdo's "Probabilistic Method" was a great mathematical idea as applied to Ramsey Theory for example and also a widely applicable trick.

Comment: I once heard a Fields Medallist say that his research consisted of interchanging the order of summation and applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @SimonWadsley: I think you may be remembering a possibly apocryphal story about Peter Lax- https://mathoverflow.net/a/60908/25028.

Comment: @SamHopkins I believe this comment is about either Terence Tao or Tim Gowers (I have heard both make roughly the same quip.)

Comment: A typical cw I would say

Comment: @GabeConant Although it has been mentioned that Rota attributed this to Feynman, I believe Feynman describes it himself in *Surely You're Joking, Mr Feynman*. The details change in each person's telling of it, so it's important to find the original. Unfortunately I lent my copy of that book to someone who never gave it back.

Comment: I am not sure what to expect from answers to this question. I always thought that the point Rota was trying to make was that a mathematician has only a small set of "tricks" that the mathematician has personalized deeply enough to always reach for and use them. Certainly we all "know" a lot more mathematics than a few tricks, but we natively are all truly fluent in a much narrower range than one would naively expect. I thought the point was that the set of techniques was particular to each mathematician. What am I missing here? @MartinSleziak's suggestion for an answer format seems reasonable.

Comment: Also, though, even if I knew all of Hilbert's tricks...I don't think I could be Hilbert. There is something to be said for the collected experience of a mathematician. I thought this was the point of Rota's passage.

Comment: @JonBannon Rota was also trying to defend Erdos' work from the charge that he only used a few tricks by noting that Hilbert and others did the same. I think the challenge with any technique or trick is to know when and how to apply it which is where experience comes into play.

Comment: A math professor once told me that all you ever do in analysis is interchange the order of limiting operations and integrate by parts.

Comment: Well, for a mathematician, a few just means finite.

Comment: I think this question misunderstands the quote; I'm surprised at so many upvotes. I think the point is that every mathematician has a few tricks that are her own. We don't necessarily know each other's tricks. That's why the observation has some real content.... i.e. it's not that everyone else is super clever and you are average because they too only have a few tricks, it's just that you do not understand their tricks, you only understand your tricks

Comment: @T_M I didn't say that all mathematicians use the same tricks. Anyway my question was not about the meaning of the quote but rather the tricks themselves and from the responses there are clearly many tricks that are common across mathematicians and fields of study.

Comment: @IvanMeir the phrase "what are *the* few tricks that Mathematicians use..." (emphasis my own of course) does indeed ask for one collection of tricks used by 'mathematicians'. And the question patently pertains to the meaning of the quotation because you also say "Assuming Rota is correct...." just before you ask the main question. I (and some others) think the question is not really correctly related to what Rota was getting at. It doesn't matter anyway, as you say there are plenty of answers...maybe they are what you were looking for??

Comment: It has always seemed to me that Rota was getting at sort of 'real', research-level tricks that are more unique to the mathematician or at least the subfield in which they worked. From outside the field, the different uses of the trick each seem like a clever leap, but with the correct knowledge in the field, they are really multiple uses of the same trick. So to my mind (and I'm sure many others), the quotation isn't really about swapping summation or the triangle inequality (two most upvoted answers!?) or things that any mathematician can easily recognise

Comment: @T_M As I said I'm more interested in the tricks themselves. Rota never went into any specifics to my knowledge so I guess we will never know exactly what he meant. It would have been interesting in particular to know which tricks he thought Hilbert used. If you have any good ones please contribute!

Comment: I see the title of the question has changed. For what it is worth, I think the other interpretation of the question is far more interesting. To find the list of generic tricks common in maths you can indeed look at the tricki. But what would be more fun is to have a list of mathematicians together with their favorite tricks. Perhaps I or someone else can provide that alternative question. If I have a minute later I will reincarnate it...

Comment: To prove a theorem, a useful and quite often used trick is to prove a few lemmas before.

Comment: @JonBannon Hi thanks for letting me know that, I've just changed the title back as I agree with you and I also don't think the title of a post should be changed in this way, quite late and not by the OP.

Comment: I posted the other interpretation just in case you wanted to stick to your change. If that other question gets shut down, please someone (@LSpice) transport @LSpice's lovely answer there over to this question.

Comment: @JonBannon Thanks Jon no problem at all. I didn't actually change the post title, someone else did which is why I reverted it as I like the slightly provocative but admittedly perhaps ambiguous original!

Comment: @IvanMeir But Rota does give some context. We will have to agree to disagree, because when you consider the comments he refers to about Erdos.... If they are referring to the common tricks that all mathematicians use, it doesn't really make sense to disparage someone's work by saying that they relied on these common tricks. The point is surely that that person thought they were clever by having realised Erdos repeated his own set of *non*-trivial combinatorial/probabilistic tricks.

Comment: FWIW I agree completely with @T_M -- as with most things in **Indiscrete Thoughts** the context in which Rota is using his rhetoric is important, and I really don't think his words should be treated as oracular truth

Comment: I actually think Rota, in the process of trying to debunk the comments about Erdos, discovered to his own surprise that Hilbert genuinely used a small set of repeated tricks. So his opinion on the matter was really independent of the comments about Erdos. In terms of the Number Theorist's remarks it is very plausible that his opinion was that Erdos used a very small set of tricks compared to other great mathematicians, not that they were particularly unique to Erdos himself.

Comment: Erdos had a large number of joint papers and worked very closely with  other mathematicians so I think it's unlikely that his own tricks were not known and used by other mathematicians and vice versa.

Comment: Perhaps though the Number Theorist was just jealous of Erdos' ability to prove difficult theorems using simple and elegant combinatorial arguments, for example, rather than lots of heavy machinery as is often the case in modern number theory!

Comment: "Illusion", Michael. A trick is something a physicist does for money.

Comment: When you find out Shelah's trick, let me know.

Comment: @IvanMeir The editor did nothing wrong when changing the title of the post; this is not bad etiquette and you should not consider it so and get offended. It was an honest attempt at clarification. Actually, I find the original title click-bait and I would prefer a more descriptive title that describes the question.

Comment: "There's all kinds of tricks in the world." "It's all one trick, man - a giant induction in outer space."

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not to be a good question, because it seems we won't learn much from the answers.

Comment: In his sixties, Rota wrote a whole slew of top-ten lists. One of them was the one about differential equations that's been mentioned on mathoverflow a number of times. One that he intended to write was "Ten problems in probability no one likes to bring up", which, while he was writing it became a list of 14 and then a list of 12, which is where he left it. Here's the one on differential equations: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Rota.pdf

Answer (score 122):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i,j}
$$

(and its variants for other measure spaces).

I still get misty-eyed whenever I read something that capitalizes on this trick in an unpredictable way.

Comment: In some ways, Fubini's theorem is just a fancy version of this.

Comment: @GabeK Yes, Fubini is indeed one of the variants. Somehow the discrete version seems much more adept at sneaking up on me though.

Comment: I tell my students in basically every class I teach always to pay attention to the order in which a double sum (or double integral, or sum-of-an-integral) first shows up, because chances are, the best thing to do next is change the order of summation/integration.

Comment: Hah, my professor Leo Goldmakher made the exact same remark in our additive combinatorics class. Something about every mathematician working with character sums having just one trick that is repeatedly used: the discrete Fubini's principle.

Comment: People have made millions on algorithm speedups based on that. Find a first integral that's stable over repeated calculations, change the order of integration, and voila! your program is several orders of magnitude faster than competitors'.

Comment: Gelfand in one of his paper  about integral geometry  mentioned   the fundamental trick which is  version of what you wrote. If $$A\stackrel{\alpha}{\leftarrow} C\stackrel{\beta}{\rightarrow} B$$ and $f$ is a function on $C$, then $$\sum_{a\in A} \sum_{\alpha(c)=a} f(c)=\sum_{b\in B}\sum_{\beta(c)=b}  f(c). $$ The inner sums are *pushforwards*  and they have counterparts in other categories.  Grothendieck  used it  succefully when applied to the (derived) category of coherent sheaves. E.g., you can get Poincare-Hopf theorem this way.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu This is very neat. What I wrote is the special case where $A=[m]$, $B=[n]$, $C=[m]\times[n]$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are projections, and $f\colon (i,j)\mapsto a_{i,j}$. Thanks Liviu!

Comment: I've been meaning to give an undergrad maths talk "correspondences in algebra, geometry, and analysis" for some time. These objects are ubiquitous! (As are the slightly more general kernels as in the answer and @LiviuNicolaescu's comment.)

Comment: I had the fortune to have Sir Tim Gowers as one of my first-year lecturers. At the end of the first lecture he finished by pointing this trick out, and said it was one of the most pratically useful techniques he'd ever come across.

Comment: @Michael can you elaborate or link? That sounds really interesting but I can't really visualize what you're saying.

Comment: @JulianC, I am currently working on [computational lithography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_lithography) in a company that makes software for semiconductor manufacturing. This area is extremely computationally intensive: for each of the trillions of target pixels you need to integrate over all pixels on the source and all the pixels on the mask between the source and the target. One of the breakthroughs was simply the change of integration order in that computation; see Chris Mack's "Fundamental Principles of Optical Lithography" for that and much more.

Comment: A variant of this is to use *counterexamples* to this when the indexing sets are not finite to give counterexamples for various questions!

Comment: @Kapil, [indeed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363119/every-mathematician-has-only-a-few-tricks#comment930128_363122), my research (computing characters of supercuspidal representations) is, in some sense, interesting precisely because of a failure of a naïve application of the Fubini theorem.

Answer (score 88):

A very useful generic trick:

If you can't prove it, make it simpler and prove that instead.

An even more useful generic trick:

If you can't prove it, make it *more complicated* and prove that instead!

Comment: The first is sometimes attributed to Polya. A related piece of wisdom due to de Giorgi: "If you can't prove your theorem, keep shifting parts of the conclusion to the assumptions, until you can."

Comment: "In dealing with mathematical problems, specialization plays, as I believe, a still more important part than generalization. Perhaps in most cases where we unsuccessfully seek the answer to a question, the cause of the failure lies in the fact that problems simpler and easier than the one in hand have been either incompletely solved, or not solved at all. Everything depends, then, on finding those easier problems and on solving them by means of devices as perfect as possible and of concepts capable of generalization...

Comment: ...This rule is one of the most important levers for overcoming mathematical difficulties; and it seems to me that it is used almost always, though perhaps unconsciously"  —David Hilbert, “Mathematical Problems”

Comment: These methods can be combined.  First generalize the problem, making it more complicated.  Then simplify along a different axis.

Comment: J. L. Alperin used to tell us first-year algebra students the second problem-solving technique, although, as far as I know, he did not claim to have invented it.

Comment: This reminds me of Zeilberger's paper on [the method of undetermined generalization and specialization](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9506215).

Comment: Another related approach which I have seen (from afar) to be successful, is to relax the axioms on some axiomatic system to make the system less rigid, yet retaining enough structure to be interesting (sometimes more so than before).

Answer (score 76):

In combinatorics: shove it into OEIS, and see what's up.
Also, add more parameters!

Note: the Macdonald polynomials were introduced by adding more parameters to the Jack and the Hall-Littlewood polynomials.
The introduction of Macdonald polynomials unified a lot of cool stuff,
and they are now essential in the field of Diagonal harmonics.

Comment: Does "snake oil" count as a trick?

Comment: That's basically the source of my PhD.

Comment: More parameters, meaning "catalytic variables"?

Comment: @SomaticCustard Well, the recent example I worked with, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362265/proof-of-certain-q-identity-for-q-catalan-numbers was solved by first generalizing the problem, (adding two additional parameters a and c).

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Nice!

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Say, switching from a modular form to a Jacobi form? Would this count as adding more parameters in your sense?

Comment: Didn't Alexander Grothendieck mention "extra parameters" as a trick, or rather insisting that one ought to think about parametrized families of mathematical objects in stead of single objects.

Answer (score 76):

Dennis Sullivan used to joke that Mikhail Gromov [only knows one thing, the triangle inequality](https://youtu.be/ixc0TNfT0ks?t=240). I would argue that many mathematicians know the triangle inequality but not many are Gromov.

Comment: Just in case somebody takes Sullivan's joke literally: I was always amazed how much analysis (including PDEs and functional analysis) Gromov knows. (As well as topology, dynamical systems,...)

Comment: In 1994, Vladimir Arnold was upset that among the Fields medalists, "three were inequalities manipulators".

Comment: Did Arnold think that number was too high, or too low?

Comment: In his book Partial Differential Relations, he showed that he also knows elementary. linear algebra.

Comment: @HarryWilson: just that it's less or equal than the sum of two other numbers of Fields medallists.

Comment: The only thing painters use is a brush

Comment: Sullivan even gave a talk where he made this triangle inequality point with Gromov in the audience. He asks Gromov if he agrees; unfortunately, the recording doesn't pick up Gromov's answer. See 4:10.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixc0TNfT0ks&ab_channel=Simplicityconference

Answer (score 55):

Integration by parts has allegedly earned some people big medals.

Comment: Perhaps a reference to: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/60908#60908

Comment: @SamHopkins: Strange, I had heard this about Laurent Schwartz: somebody in his entourage jokingly said "so now one gets the Fields medal for integrating by parts"?

Comment: @AlexM.: apocryphal stories like this can often shift and evolve, involving different people, etc.

Comment: Transferring that derivative from one function to the other can be life changing.

Comment: Is the Attiyah-Singer Index Theorem not "just integration by parts" ?

Answer (score 48):

For a finite set of real numbers, the maximum is at least the average and the minimum is at most the average.

Of course this is just the real version of the Pigeonhole Principle, but Dijkstra had an eloquent argument as to why the usual version is inferior.

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD10xx/EWD1094.html

Comment: I'm glad I came here today if for nothing else than to have read that piece by Dijkstra. Thank you for the link.

Comment: I'm not convinced of the superiority of the other version. It only makes sense for real numbers. What's wrong with "if $A$ has more elements than $B$, then there is no injection $A\to B$"? This version works even for infinite sets (and indeed, it's a commonly used trick).

Comment: The pigeonhole principle wins my vote, partly because it has such a memorable name and because you can explain it to your six year old. And it really is useful.

Answer (score 47):

Although Erdős was mentioned in the comments as perhaps having prompted this whole discussion, I'm surprised not to see the basic trick of "try a random object/construction" posted as an answer, which he used so often to such great success.

Comment: what do you mean by "try a random object/construction"?

Comment: E.g. to prove that some graph exists satisfying a given property, show this holds with positive (or even high) probability for the random graph $G(n,p)$. This is also often called the "probabilistic method."

Answer (score 34):

If an integer-valued function is continuous, it has to be constant.

This trick shows up in many places, such as the proof Rouché's theorem, and basic results about the Fredholm index.

Comment: ...as long as the domain is connected! I happen to have a continuous, integer-valued, non-constant function in my pocket right now. (It's the function which maps each point inside of a piece of currency to the face value of that piece of currency in cents.)

Comment: @TannerSwett How is your function not constant?

Comment: @Allawonder Tanner must have two coins of distinct values in their pocket. Different coins are different connected components of the domain. Each coin maps to its own value, so the function is only locally constant.

Comment: @Allawonder How about the continuous integer-valued non-constant function $\operatorname{id} \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 33):

Whenever you find yourself trying to implement inclusion–exclusion by hand ... stop immediately and start over using the Möbius $\mu$-function.

Answer (score 30):

Those of us who are old enough may remember http://www.tricki.org/

Localize + complete, taking a hypersurface section, and using the socle are useful tricks in commutative algebra.

Comment: I scoffed at your first sentence, then quickly had a terrible realisation.

Comment: I've been looking for a reference on the 'localize and complete' type of trick.  Can you give an example of the technique in action (or a paper where I should take a look)?

Comment: @HarryGindi: there are countless examples. Often, a property can be checked locally, then completion allows one to use Cohen's structure theorem, thus working concretely over power series. One not very simple but powerful result where that procedure works is the following: If $R$ is a regular Noetherian algebra containing a field and $M,N$ be f.g modules, then $Tor_i^R(M,N)=0$ implies $Tor_j^R(M,N)$ for all $j\geq i$ (the so-called rigidity of Tor).

Comment: @HailongDao Thanks! Nice one!

Comment: Am I the only person who has to wilfully resist pronouncing tricki as "tritsky"?

Comment: @RobertFurber Is that you, comrade?

Comment: @RobertFurber Whatever happend to Leon Tritsky? But seriously, it depends on the distance from English. For those with this distance bigger than distance to Russian, it is rather "treeskee".

Answer (score 30):

Not sure if...
well, what the...

Find a duality. Play duals against each other.

Comment: Duality is everywhere. It often appears in subtle and unexpected ways. Surprisingly powerful for something that sounds so simple.

Comment: And yet, curiously, [triality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triality) doesn't seem to be 50% more powerful as a trick.  (Or maybe I just haven't grokked how to use it properly!)

Comment: @LSpice Maybe because playing three guys against each other is much more tricky

Comment: @LSpice: Well... every vector space has a dual, but triality only exists in a few dimensions.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, fair enough; but perhaps one could also suspect that structure that's available all the time must be less powerful than structure that is available in only a few cases.

Answer (score 29):

[Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)
and the special cases, Cauchy-Buniakovski-Schwarz

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz, arguably, is the only trick in analytic number theory

Comment: [Cauchy Schwarz Master Class](https://www.amazon.com/Cauchy-Schwarz-Master-Class-Introduction-Mathematical-ebook/dp/B00KILLJLA) granted it isn't only about Cauchy Schwarz...

Comment: Just imagine, how much would number theorists prove if they use general Hölder inequality instead.

Answer (score 29):

If $1-x$ is invertible, then its inverse is $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots $. This is the second most useful "trick" I know, after "look for the [symmetric] group acting on you thing", but someone else already mentioned it.

Comment: So for x=2.....

Comment: @Pablo Care to share useful instances of your trick?

Comment: @lalala, for $x = 2$, the inverse is exactly as stated.  In $\mathbb Q_2$, anyway.

Comment: If $x$ is nilpotent, then $1-x$ is invertible

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez parametrices constructions

Answer (score 29):

I couldn't resist adding one of my own: *"Apply linearity of expectation"*.

For example in Barbier's incredibly elegant approach ([Buffon's Noodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_noodle#Bending_the_needle)) to [Buffon's Needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem) Problem.

Comment: Jordan Ellenberg gives a nice popular exposition of this (linearity of expectation in general, and the Buffon's noodle problem in particular) in "[How not to be wrong](https://www.jordanellenberg.com/how-not-to-be-wrong)".

Comment: This is arguably a special case of Conant's answer.

Comment: [@GabeConant's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363122) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363119/every-mathematician-has-only-a-few-tricks/363331#comment965472_363323) by @TerryTao.

Answer (score 25):

What worked very well for the French school of algebraic geometry (but it seems to predate them!) is the "French trick" of turning a theorem into a definition. See e.g. [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34717) for some examples and background on the term.

Answer (score 24):

If $r,s $ are elements of a ring, then $1-rs$ invertible implies  $1-sr$ is invertible (and it is a trick: you can make an educated guess for the  formula for the inverse of $1-sr$ from that for $1-rs$). This can be used to find quick proofs of: (a) in a Banach algebra, ${\rm spec\ } rs \cup \{0\} = {\rm spec}\ sr \cup \{0\}$ (which in turn yields the nonsolvability of $xy-yx = 1$---all one needs is boundedness and nonemptiness of the spectrum); (b) the Jacobson radical (defined as the intersection of all maximal right ideals) is a two-sided ideal; and probably some other things I can't think of right now ...

Comment: This trick is due to Halmos, right?—or at least he wrote up a nice explanation of it.

Comment: Halmos did explain the motivation for the method (power series) in one of his books. Jacobson in his 1930s (?) book (Theory of rings) must have included it. But I think there is an 1910s paper of either Burnside or Wedderburn which deals with this and a generalization.

Comment: Percy Deift has called the Sylvester determinant identity $\mathrm{det}(1+AB)=\mathrm{det}(1+BA)$ "the most important identity in mathematics".

Answer (score 22):

In the course of working with Hervé Jacquet and reading many of his papers on automorphic forms and the relative trace formula, I feel like he got an amazing amount of mileage out of clever use of *change of variables*.

I remember a conference where all the speakers gave extremely hard-to-follow talks using very sophisticated machinery, and then Jacquet gave a talk with a very nice result and about 45 minutes of it was going through an elementary proof (once you knew the setup) that boiled down to a clever sequence of change of variables.

Comment: I like this answer as it is more in the spirit of what Rota seemed to be referring to

Comment: Classical physics is all about this! Hamiltonian/Lagrangian mechanics, Hamilton-Jacobi theory, canonical transformations, finding conserved quantities etc. involve clever choice of variables.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe more than a "trick," but if you want to investigate a sequence
$a_0,a_1,\dots$, then look at a generating function such as $\sum
a_nx^n$ or $\sum a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$. If you are interested in a
function $f:\mathrm{Par}\to R$, where $R$ is a commutative ring and
$\mathrm{Par}$ is the set of all partitions $\lambda$ of all integers
$n\geq 0$, then look at a generating function $\sum_\lambda
f(\lambda) N_\lambda b_\lambda$, where $\{b_\lambda\}$ is one of the standard
bases for symmetric functions and $N_\lambda$ is a normalizing factor
(analogous to $1/n!$). For instance, if $f^\lambda$ is the
number of standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$, then
$\sum_\lambda f^\lambda s_\lambda = 1/(1-s_1)$, where $s_\lambda$ is a
Schur function. If $f(\lambda)$ is the number of square roots
of a permutation $\lambda\in\mathfrak{S}_n$ of cycle type $\lambda$,
then
$$ \sum_\lambda f(\lambda)z_\lambda^{-1} p_\lambda = \sum_\lambda
  s_\lambda = \frac{1}{\prod_i (1-x_i)\cdot \prod_{i<j} (1-x_ix_j)},
  $$
where $p_\lambda$ is a power sum symmetric function and
$z_\lambda^{-1}$ is a standard normalizing factor.

Answer (score 20):

**The Renormalization Group trick:**

Suppose you have some object $v_0$ and you want to understand a feature $Z(v_0)$ of that object. First identify $v_0$ as some element of a set $E$ of similar objects. Suppose one can extend the definition of $Z$ to all objects $v\in E$. If $Z(v_0)$ is too difficult to address directly, the renormalization group approach consists in finding a transformation $RG:E\rightarrow E$ which satisfies $\forall v\in E, Z(RG(v))=Z(v)$, namely, which preserves the feature of interest. If one is lucky, after infinite iteration $RG^n(v_0)$ will converge to a fixed point $v_{\ast}$ of $RG$ where $Z(v_{\ast})$ is easy to compute.

Example 1: (due to Landen and Gauss)

Let $E=(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ and for $v=(a,b)\in E$ suppose the "feature of interest" is the value of the integral
$$
Z(v)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}}\ .
$$
A good transformation one can use is $RG(a,b):=\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\sqrt{ab}\right)$.

Example 2: $E$ is the set of probability laws of real-valued random variables say $X$ which are centered and with variance equal to $1$. The feature of interest is the limit law of $\frac{X_1+\cdots+ X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$. Here the $X_i$ are independent copies of the original random variable $X$.

A good transformation here is $RG({\rm law\ of\ }X):={\rm law\ of\ }\frac{X_1+X_2}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Fantastic. I wish you also could explained Conformal Symmetry in a similar simplified language.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266921/how-is-the-conformal-prediction-conformal

Comment: just gave it a try

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394335/what-is-a-simplified-intuitive-explanation-of-conformal-invariance/394363

Answer (score 19):

Andre Weil's slogan that where there is a difficulty, look for the group (that unravels it).

I take this to mean something more aggressive than a truism to note and use group structure; more like "exploit the full potential of representation theory in all its manifestations after seeking out whatever obvious and hidden symmetries exist in the problem".

Answer (score 18):

The chapter ‘A Different Box Of Tools’ of [Surely You're Joking, Mr Feynman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surely_You%27re_Joking,_Mr._Feynman!) was named for a particular trick Richard Feymnan used:

> [*Calculus For The Practical Man*] showed how to differentiate parameters under the integral sign — it's a certain operation.  It turns out that's not taught very much in the universities; they don't emphasise it.  But I caught on how to use that method, and I used that one damn tool again and again.

(pp.86–87)

Comment: I asked about Feynman's trick [elsewhere on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/50837) and got some interesting responses.

Answer (score 16):

**(1) Double-counting**, which can also be described as counting the same thing in two ways. Very useful, and at least as powerful as interchanging summation order.

**(2) Induction**. When there is a natural number size parameter, one can always consider trying this.

**(3) Extremal principle**, which is ultimately based on induction, but looks very different. For example, [the Sylvester-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) has an extremely simple proof using this.

Comment: (2) can maybe be generalised to *structural* induction, so that one need not even artificially wrangle a natural-number parameter at all (e.g., directly inducting on trees, by, say, deducing a property of a tree if the same property holds when one leaf is removed, rather than on their height).

Comment: @LSpice: Indeed. [Structural induction should even be taught in that way (top-down)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10034/1550). =)

Answer (score 16):

Existence as a property: You want to find an object that solves a given equation or a given problem. Generalize what you mean by object so that existence becomes easy or at least tractable. Being an object is now a possible property you might prove about your generalized object.
Having already something you can prove properties about is often both mathematically and psychologically easier than searching in the void.

Some examples:

- Algebraic closures: In your original field, you don't know whether your polynomial has zeros, but in the algebraic closure it does. If you can show that it is Galois invariant, then it is actually in the original field. (Given that complex numbers are an algebraic closure (though unknown at the time of their conception), this is maybe the most classical of these examples.)
- Representability of moduli problems: Often it is hard to show that a moduli problem is representable by a quasi-projective variety. This is what lead Weil to define general varieties so that he could represent a moduli problem. If your moduli problem does not have automorphisms and you can produce an ample line bundle, you can show afterwards that it is actually represented by a quasi-projective variety.
- Partial differential equations: Often it is much easier to find generalized solutions (Sobolev functions or a distribution). Then the existence of a classical solution is a regularity property of you generalized solution.

Comment: A great one! Reminds of Bertrand Russell's famous "The method of "postulating" what we want has many advantages; they are the same as the advantages of theft over honest toil." ([Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell#Introduction_to_Mathematical_Philosophy_(1919))), 1919

Answer (score 15):

A common trick is [compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)). First prove that a space admits a compactification, e.g.

- [Gromov's compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_compactness_theorem_(geometry)) for manifolds with positive Ricci curvature and bounded diameter
- [Gromov's compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_compactness_theorem_(topology)) for pseudoholomorphic curves
- the integers with the profinite topology has compactification the [profinite integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer) $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$
- The space of hyperbolic 3-manifolds with basepoints in the thick part with respect to the [Gromov-Hausdorff topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence) is compact
- [Geometrically finite Kleinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_finiteness) groups maybe be compactified (sometimes) by adjoining the domain of discontinuity (the conformal compactification)
- the space of curves on a surface compactifies to [projective measured lamination space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thurston_boundary#Measured_foliations_on_surfaces)
- The space of [probability measures on a compact space is compact with respect to weak* convergence](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_of_probability_measures#:%7E:text=also%20Complete%20space%3B%20Separable%20space,0%20as%20n%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E.) (I guess this is not a compactification, but really a proof of compactness in the right topology)
- Surfaces in $R^3$ with bounded area and fixed boundary may be compactified by the space of [integral currents with the flat distance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_convergence#Compactness_theorem)

Once one has a compact space, one can analyze the objects one is interested in by taking infinite sequences, extracting a subsequence in the limit, and analyzing this limit, sometimes obtaining a contradiction if the limit does not lie in the original space one was considering. E.g. I used this approach to analyze [exceptional Dehn fillings of cusped hyperbolic 3-manifolds](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2680207).

Comment: In some sense, this is a particularly geometric way of the technique I describe in my answer, namely to generalize the kind of objects one is considering to make existence easy. In the compactification, existence of a converging subsequence is suddenly automatic; and once one has a point in the compactification, one has techniques to possibly show it's in the original space.

Comment: One might add to this list compactifications of moduli spaces - say, adding to moduli spaces of smooth curves those with nodal singular points. Among other miracles, this ties together moduli spaces of curves of different genera.

Answer (score 13):

The second derivative test (i.e. "a smooth function has a local maximum at a critical point with non-positive second derivative.") is endlessly useful.

When you first see this fact in Calculus, it might not seem so powerful. However, there are countless generalizations (e.g. the maximum principle for elliptic and parabolic PDEs), which play an important role in analysis.

Comment: If the powerful tool of linearity isn’t good enough, the basic concept of convexity is amazingly powerful.

Comment: @DeaneYang, indeed, it amazes me how a first-order approximation is good, a second-order approximation often allows one to wring out a little more power … and yet, outside hard analysis (and I guess the higher reciprocity laws of number theory?), it seems that third-order approximations are either not so useful, or so hard to use that we aren't able to elevate them to the status of tricks yet.

Answer (score 13):

There's the quote in Bell's Men of Mathematics attributed to Jacobi: "You must always invert", as Jacobi said when asked the secret of his mathematical discoveries. Sounds apocryphal but it is certainly a nice suggestion.

Comment: Buffett and Munger are also known to have incorporated this principle into their investing philosophy.

Comment: Presumably this is related to elliptic integrals giving *inverse* elliptic functions, just as integrals like $\int \frac{1}{x} dx$ gives the inverse to the exponential function and $\int \frac{1}{1+ x^2} dx$ gives the inverse to the tangent function.

Comment: Sure, but since most problems can be written as a map to invert, the advice sound comical

Comment: @Favst, how does one use this advice to drive investment?  (Or is it a joke?)

Comment: @LSpice, it's mentioned in "Poor Charlie's Almanack: The Wit and Wisdom of Charles T. Munger" and many websites that seek to understand and emulate Buffett and Munger. Some details are given here: https://seekingalpha.com/article/4040474-invert-always-invert . I'm no investor though, so I'm not entirely sure how this philosophy applies practically in day-to-day investments.

Comment: @Favst, thanks.  So the 'invert' here isn't 'compositional inverse', but literally 'turn upside-down', or whatever (even in Jacobi's sense, as the expanded quote they include indicates).

Comment: (I [made a mistake](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363119/every-mathematician-has-only-a-few-tricks/363156#comment916667_363156):  the expanded quote is from Munger.  The Jacobi quote is just as quoted, and probably indeed means what a mathematician thinks it means rather than what Munger's quote suggests it means.)

Comment: Jacobi: 'man muss immer umkehren' is reported in Edward B. Van Vleck, Current tendencies of mathematical research, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 23 (1916), 1–13.

Answer (score 12):

If, on a probability space, $\int_\Omega X\,dP = x$, then there is some $\omega$ such that $X(\omega)\ge x$.

Comment: A useful generalization of this trick: https://mathoverflow.net/a/363178/35357

Answer (score 12):

In homotopy theory: if something is hard to compute, build an infinite tower that converges to it and induct your way up the tower. This includes spectral sequences, Postnikov towers, and Goodwillie calculus.

In category theory: apply Yoneda's Lemma.

Other common tricks in category theory:

- Swap the order of colimits.
- Embed into a presheaf category (e.g., Giraud's Theorem).
- Reduce to the case of representable functors.

In an [old mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19325/most-striking-applications-of-category-theory/291011#291011), I wrote several more common tricks in category theory, including

- Localization: shifting view so that two objects you previously viewed as different are now viewed as the same.
- Replacing an object by one which is easier to work with but has the same fundamental properties you are trying to study.
- Mapping an object to a small bit of information about the object. Showing that two are different because they differ on this bit.

Comment: Good that you mentioned representability and Giraud! Making non-representable functors representable is an extremely powerful trick. In fact something similar is omnipresent in the whole mathematics: if something you want to exist does not exist, - make it exist!

Comment: Concerning localization - more specific advantage of this trick is that instead of *identifying* objects one *adds* an isomorphism between them: extending your domain is usually technically easier than quotienting it by an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 11):

Scott Aaronson has taken a stab at articulating his own methodology for [upper-bounding the probability of something bad](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=3712).  He was inspired by a blog post by Scott Alexander bemoaning how rarely experts write down their expert knowledge in detail.

Answer (score 9):

My favorite is perhaps the "commutator trick", i.e. "take commutators and see what happens". Some general things that may happen 1) the commutator touches less than the commutatorands 2) the commutator defies your abelian intuition.

I'm mostly familiar with 1) in the context of infinite groups, in particular finding generators for complicated groups, and 2) blew my mind to pieces as Barrington's theorem before I even knew any math.

I counted that a seventh of my papers use some type of commutator trick, but what really sold commutators to me was when I got a Rubik's cube as a christmas present.

Comment: The obvious example for 1) is how you prove simplicity/perfection of alternating simple groups and others like it.

Answer (score 9):

From a physicist point of view I want to mention this trick and its generalization for operators:

```
      "Two commuting matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable"
```

(for physicists all matrices are diagonalizable). Of course the idea is that if you know the eigenvectors of one matrix/operator then diagonalizing the other one is much easier. Here are some applications.

1)The system is translation invariant : Because the eigenvectors of the translation operator are $e^{ik.x}$, then one should use the Fourier transform.  It solves all the wave equations for light, acoustics, of free quantum electrons or the heat equation in homogeneous media.

2)The system has a discrete translation symmetry: The typical system is the atoms in a solid state that form a crystal. We have a discrete translation operator $T_a\phi(x)=\phi(x+a)$ with $a$ the size of the lattice and then we should try $\phi_k(x+a)=e^{ik.a}\phi_k(x)$ as it is an eigenvector of $T_a$. This gives the  [Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem)-[Floquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) theory where the spectrum is divided into band structure. It is one of the most famous model of condensed matter as it explains the different between conductors or insulators.

3)The system is rotational invariant: One should then use and diagonalize the rotation operator first. This will allow us to find the eigenvalue/eigenvectors of the [Hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom). By the way we notice the eigenspace of the Hydrogen are stable by rotation and are therefore finite dimension representations of $SO(3)$. The irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ have dimension 1,3,5,... and they appears, considering also the spin of the electron, as the [columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell) of the periodic table of the elements (2,6,10,14,...).

4)$SU(3)$ symmetry: Particle physics is extremely complicated. However physicists have discovered that there is an underlying $SU(3)$ symmetry. Then considering the representations of $SU(3)$ the zoology of particles seems much more organized ([A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#/media/File:Baryon-decuplet.svg), [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#/media/File:Meson_nonet_-_spin_0.svg)).

Comment: If "for physicists, all matrices are diagonalizable", what about the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Is it for physicists "almost all" $\approx$ "all"?

Comment: @ogogmad For physicists all matrices are diagonalizable except for the matrices than are not.

Answer (score 9):

Terence Tao wrote a paper, [Exploring the toolkit of Jean Bourgain](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06736). The abstract reads:

> Gian-Carlo Rota once asserted that "every mathematician only has a few tricks". The sheer breadth and ingenuity in the work of Jean Bourgain may at first glance appear to be a counterexample to this maxim. However, as we hope to illustrate in this article, even Bourgain relied frequently on a core set of tools, which formed the base from which problems in many disparate mathematical fields could then be attacked. We discuss a selected number of these tools here, and then perform a case study of how an argument in one of Bourgain's papers can be interpreted as a sequential application of several of these tools.

Answer (score 6):

**The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**, that is
$$\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} \psi_t \, dt =\psi_1 - \psi_0.$$ This   "trick" is used throughout differential topology/geometry, for example in showing that the de-Rham cohomology is invariant or for a uniform bound on the period of a negative gradient flow line of the Rabinowitz action functional in constructing Rabinowitz--Floer homology. Actually, the *trick* consists of cleverly bringing the statement in question down to the form where one can apply the fundamnetal theorem of calculus. Also, in Floer theory in general, **Ascoli's theorem** (or Arzelà-Ascolis theorem) is used in an exceeding amount.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus has served me well in my research.

Answer (score 6):

I went through all the responses, and I'm surprised that the following trick has not already been posted, given its ubiquity: **Use antisymmetry in a partially ordered set.** That is, if $a\le b$ and $b\le a$ then $a=b.$

Examples:

1. Real numbers: $a\le b$ and $b\le a$ implies $a=b$ (can be helpful when directly showing equality is difficult)
2. Divisibility of positive integers: $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ implies $a=b$ (extremely common in number theory)
3. Subsets of a set: $a\subseteq b$ and $b\subseteq a$ implies $a=b$ (for example, in locus proofs of classical geometry)

Answer (score 5):

Find something that can be computed (a special case, a simplification, or just something of the same flavor as the real problem). Then stare at the data and look for patterns.

Answer (score 5):

Using some form of Yoneda's Lemma, see your particular structure as representable functor in an abstract category where your desired constructions are obvious.

This functorial point of view is very nice in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 4):

This trick is called “stupid argument” by some of my collaborators and me.

Let’s say you have a property that is defined on testing using cubes on all scales. Now you have some regular set (say again a cube or a ball) in which the property holds, that is, if you test with a cube that is contained in this regular set then it holds. You might come in this situation for example by local transformation of sets with this property, like flattening the boundary in PDE. Now to get it for all cubes you make the following case distinction: if the concentric cube of half the size is contained in the regular set, you use your assumption. Otherwise, the original cube contains a cube of 1/4 side length compared to the original one that is completely outside the regular set and for this one you get the property usually trivially.

Since this is a trick, I kept it somehow mysterious. Applicability includes things like measure theoretic dimensions, metric properties like porousity and so on and the exact details why it’s trivial “outside” and why testing with comparably smaller objects is ok depends a bit on the specific property one aims for.

Answer (score 4):

John Allen Paulos has referred to the parable of the Texas sharpshooter a number of times.  To paraphrase:

> A man driving across the US notices that in a west Texas town, there are a lot of barns with targets painted on their side.  Each of the targets have bulletholes directly within the bullseye.  Impressed, the man inquires in a local diner about the ace shooter who lives in the town.  The townsfolk inform him that a local resident just likes to shoot randomly at barns, and then later on will paint the target right where the bullets land!

Although parable is often referred to as a [fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy) of logical reasoning, there appears to be more of a mathematical trick to the logic - namely, conditioning on a random event may be fruitful, even if the probability of the specific random event is low.

This Texas sharpshooter parable to me seems similar to, for example, the post-selection tricks of [scatter-shot boson sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson_sampling#Scattershot_boson_sampling) and variants used in recent (2020) experiments.  Therein one has limited control over the generation of individual photons, so one merely post-selects on the particular $M$ crystals that generated the photons.

Answer (score 3):

There is but **one** major trick, and furthermore, many of the other answers are applications of it. Let's call it

> *T R A N S L A T I O N*

The idea is very simple; you translate your problem to a language in which it is simple to solve, so you solve it, and then (if necessary) translate your solution back to the original language. Alternatively, you can think of this as finding the right angle of attack to solve your problem.

1. Conjugation? Say $W$ is a sequence of Rubik moves that twists two corners. Find moves $V$ that puts the corners you want to twist in the correct position. The n simply apply $VWV^{-1}$.
2. Change of variables? Translate your integral in $x$ to an integral in $u$ (with translated differential and bounds of course). Find the antiderivative as a function of $u$, and translate back to a function of $x$ (or evaluate if definite).
3. Diagonalization? Find an eigenbase (essentially a convenient language to understand your matrix). Change basis by conjugation, and your matrix action suddenly looks much simpler.
4. Analytic geometry? Translate your geometric problem to convenient algebraic manipulations.
5. etc.

Comment: This is usually some form of abstraction, and indeed it can be quite powerful. In some sense, this is even the definition of mathematics. Finding an abstraction that unifies and answers easily many apparently unrelated questions.

Comment: I also mention the Rubik's cube in my answer, so let me note that when I got my first Rubik's cube as a kid, I certainly invented conjugation immediately. But I did not invent commutators, and was not able to solve the cube. (I don't disagree with your answer though.)

Comment: There's a book about this trick, called _Bypass Operations_.

Answer (score 3):

**If a function with connected domain is locally constant, then it is constant.**

Connectedness doesn't need to be understood topologically: one manifestation of the trick is that a sequence whose consecutive terms are equal must be constant.
If the domain is nice enough, it extends to periodic functions as well (a locally periodic function has the same periodic pattern everywhere).

Comment: If any two horses are of the same color, then all horses are of the same color.

Answer (score 2):

Two come to mind for me.

1. "When in doubt, differentiate!" -Chern (or so I've heard).
   As a result, it's been useful for me to check the implications of $d^2=0$ on differential forms.
2. I have not used it in research (I have moved away from analysis somewhat),  but I love trying to use Jensen's inequality when I come across an analysis problem. If I recall correctly, I solved two problems on my analysis prelim exam using said inequality.

Comment: When working in coordinates, as with PDEs, checking what happens when you commute partial derivatives is indeed quite useful. 

Jensen’s inequality is really just the definition of convexity. So it encompasses all other inequalities based on convexity. Looking for convexity and then applying the direct consequence of its definition is an impressively useful and powerful “trick”

Answer (score 2):

Geometrise!

It worked well for Newton in his *Principia* when he didn't think that mathematicians would swallow the results he had found for calculus.

For Lie, when he considered PDEs and their solutions.

It worked well for Minkowski when he geometrised Special realtivity and this was helpful for Einsteins work on GR; although he has said that he didn't think of his theory as geometrical, he thought of physically as a unification of inertia and gravity.

Also for Noether when left a note about Betti numbers were better understood as groups and also lectured on them.

It also worked well for Zariski and Grothendieck when they geometrised lots of number theory.

Also Mechanise!

It worked for Archimedes when calculating various volumes.

It also worked for Witten, when he given a problem by Atiyah when he asked Witten to discover a physical understanding of the HOMFLY knot invariant.

Answer (score 2):

Taylor expansion. Much of the classical theory of statistics (and some of its modern extensions) revolves around performing a second-order Taylor expansion of the likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

Proof "tricks" that are routinely used by many:

- Induction
- Contradiction

Computational and proof "tricks":

- Interchanging the order of summation/integration
- Counting the same thing in multiple ways
- Looking for patterns (compute special cases, etc.)

Less applicable to as many problems, but still applicable to a wide range of problems in fields like Computer Science, we have the [Repertoire Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017498/mathematical-explanation-for-the-repertoire-method/1023510).

More specialized in mathematics, there are also various methods related to exponential sums, e.g., van der Corput's, Vinogradov's, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A closed discrete subset of a compact space is finite!

Comment: [*Closed* discrete subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80802/is-a-discrete-set-inside-a-compact-space-necessarily-finite)...

Comment: Oh, you are right! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of all mathematicians of all times. When you write:

> Assuming Rota is correct, what are the few tricks that mathematicians use repeatedly,

it seems that you interpreted Rota's words as follows:

> There is a set of tricks  $\mathcal{T}$, with $|\mathcal{T}|\ll 10^{10}$, such that every $m\in\mathcal{M}$ uses only tricks from $\mathcal{T}$,

when in fact he meant:

> For every $m\in\mathcal{M}$, there is a set of tricks $\mathcal{T}_m$, with $|\mathcal{T}_m|\ll 10^{10}$, such that $m$ uses only tricks from $\mathcal{T}_m$.

Therefore, you should first specify $m$ to get a description of $\mathcal{T}_m$. Most of the posted answers address indeed this kind of question after having selected a suitable subset $S\subset \mathcal{M}$.