# Hard problems solving tricks

Tags: mathematics-education, teaching, problem-solving

This question is motivated by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996961/hard-problems-solving-tricks/) that I posted on math.stackexchange.

When I fail to solve a hard math problem (like the ones I presented in the linked post), I read a solution and I noticed that many times it includes a *trick* that I didn't see. I try to memorize it and make it mine, but sometimes it's very hard to do so because I don't see the thinking-process behind the trick (like for $\phi$ [here](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/finite-subgroups-of-gln-z/)). And this frustrates me. My questions are:

- Is it a common feeling in research?
- I wonder if I should write a list of tricks (that I'll update every time I see one), is that a good idea?
- Do you have any advice on how to get better at solving such problems? (I know that experience and mathematical maturity help a lot)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There's probably more than one way to prove the theorem you link to, and certainly some of the proofs are more clearly motivated. It's a very nice trick anyway, and mapping into a different group is a natural thing to do. Expecting this to solve the question isn't necessarily.

Comment: Do tricks really exist in mathematics? I'm not sure.

Comment: @PietroMajer By trick I don't mean a magical result, but a new method or a result I don't immediately see where it can come from... Completing the square is a trick we learned to solve quadratic equations for example.

Comment: There is this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363119/every-mathematician-has-only-a-few-tricks quite popular MO question ...