# Approach to learning constructive QFT

Tags: soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

First I would like to apologize if this post breaks any rule regarding career advice or opinion-based questions. Given that construct QFT (CQFT) is a rather small community, I found this is the only site where some current/past practitioners can chime in.

For an idea of my mathematical level, in terms of analysis I have finished Folland's book on real analysis (which is mainly about measure/integration theory and basic parts of functional analysis) and I am currently going through Reed & Simon's book on functional analysis. I am also comfortable with general topology and I have gone through most of Tu's book on (smooth) manifolds. I also know a little bit of PDE theory. On the physics side of things, I am largely self taught and I have gone through most of Folland's book on QFT, Hall's book on quantum mechanics, and a small smattering of Peskin & Schroeder. The major physics topic I am not very familiar with is E&M, which makes learning from physics books difficult as they often teach QFT through QED.

I am interesting in going into CQFT, but I am a little puzzled on the best way to go about it. I read a few other questions on here that provide some very nice resources. The problem I am having is some of the math-oriented books assume too much math and the physicists assume too much physics (and speak in a completely different language than what I am used to as a mathematics student). Should I be learning QFT from only CQFT texts, or should I use traditional/heuristic physics books as well (e.g. Peskin & Schroeder) to get an intuition about the subject? Is there any other approach that is recommended?

Comment: While it's not about CQFT per se, you might want to look at Talagrand's recent book *What Is a Quantum Field Theory?* It's a serious yet mathematician-friendly introduction to QFT.

Comment: @TimothyChow Thank you for your suggestion. I actually have a copy of that book and used it as a supplement when going through Folland's book.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CQFT is very much still an open research subject.  I don't think it is known what the best approach is.  So all I can do is share my own opinion.  (And a warning: I'm just an interested observer!)

First: **Learn you some classical electrodynamics!**  Quantum field theory is after all *a theory of fields*, and classical electrodynamics is the main example of a field theory!  Skipping it is a bit like skipping spheres to study homotopy categories.

Electrodynamics books tend to be a little cluttered, since they must also serve the needs of future engineers and experimentalists.  You could skip around in Griffiths or Jackson, but I think the most efficient & logical approach to the core material of electrodynamics is [Landau & Lifshiftz, Volume 2](https://ia903206.us.archive.org/4/items/landau-and-lifshitz-physics-textbooks-series/Vol%202%20-%20Landau%2C%20Lifshitz%20-%20The%20classical%20theory%20of%20fields%20%284th%2C%201994%29.pdf).  Landau takes a straight route to Maxwell's equations, and then treats electro- and magnetostatics, EM waves, scattering and so forth as applications.

---

To your larger question:  I think you should not attempt to read the CQFT literature without reading some of the physics literature as well.  The CQFT literature doesn't exist in isolation, so studying it alone is at best only hearing part of a conversation.  For another, most of the existing textbooks on CQFT are basically research monographs.  You're expected to bring some intuition for the problem domain.  (The exception to this is Dimock's [Quantum Mechanics & Quantum Field Theory:  A Mathematical Primer](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-mechanics-and-quantum-field-theory/06B6B13B344880D492F4A09C9C1E713D), which could only be better if it were longer.)

But the physics literature is very large!  And written by people who either enjoy trolling mathematicians or are genuinely unable to distinguish between the $SO(3)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.  So, yes, you have to be choosy.  Since how to be choosy is a matter of taste, this is where I get opinionated.

A few suggestions, specifically about which physics books to read to gain intuition and context.  (I'll let others try to make a map to topics of contemporary interest in CQFT.)

**Avoid particle physics**.

So many people have gone down this road, and it doesn't go anywhere!  You just end up with mathematical translations of Peskin & Schroeder.  Lots of calculational techniques, very few quantum fields.  Frankly, I think this approach is basically doomed.  Particle physics is:

- too complicated:  the details of the calculations obscures the basic structures.
- not well understood: e.g., the infrared structure of even *trivial* theories like the quantum Maxwell theory is one of the [major research themes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448) of the past decade, never mind the problem of confinement.
- probably broken at a foundational level:  It's highly likely that neither quantum electrodynamics nor the Higgs field nor the Standard Model itself actually exists as a continuum model.

So the easy examples don't exist, in the same sense that the translation invariant probability measure on the integers doesn't exist, and the harder examples are so hard you might win a Millenium prize.  I'm not saying don't study particle physics, but don't make it your only focus.

**Learn QFT via statistical physics**

Take the other path:  Learn QFT from the statistical physicists.  It's easier!  They have non-trivial solvable examples!   In low dimensions!  Also: the core organizing principle of QFT -- renormalization as a means of isolating the low-frequency behavior -- was discovered by people doing statistical physics (Kadanoff & Wilson), so you might as well follow along in their footsteps.

Also, there's so much good mathematics here, from basic analysis and combinatorics in the classical theory of gases up to the recent work of Fields medalists like Hairer and Duminil-Copin.

If I were doing it over again, I'd probably read Goodstein's [States of Matter](https://store.doverpublications.com/048664927x.html) together with Ruelle's more rigorous [Statistical Mechanics: Rigorous Results](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4090#t=aboutBook).  Then progress to  Shankar's [Quantum Field Theory and Condensed Matter: An Introduction](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-field-theory-and-condensed-matter/2CA9970800C3D31D6E641736186B3FBD).  Also, Baxter's [Exactly Solved Models in Statistical Mechanics](https://physics.anu.edu.au/research/ftp/mpg/baxter_book.php).

**Spend some time learning about QFT on curved spacetimes**.

You learned all that differential geometry, so you might as well use it!   And thinking about what QFT on curved spacetime should be is a good thing to do, since it forces you to focus on the fundamentals.  You can't just Fourier analyze everything in sight.

If you're a mathematician, the best thing to do here is to read Robert Wald's writings, starting with the little red book [Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime and Black Hole Thermodynamics](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/Q/bo3684008.html).  Wald is a very careful thinker and writer and he works with mathematics in very tasteful ways.  (And I just learned, he's also written a [grad level textbook on electromagnetism](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism), which looks like a nice alternative to Landau.)

Even if you don't want to think about black holes and the like, you should make an effort to understand the Unruh Effect:  Observers in relatively accelerated rest frames *in flat Minkowski space* will agree on the value of a quantum field at a point, but they will not agree on how many particles are in a system.  The reality of particles depends on the representation of the algebra of observables.

**Read lattice QFT papers**

The physics literature on lattice QFT tends to have very clear definitions.  They have to, because they're usually oriented towards numerical simulations, and you can't just hand-wave the details to a computer.  It's also usually the starting point for rigorous CQFT constructions.

Start off with LePage's [Lattice QCD for Novices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-lat/0506036.pdf).  Then (if you still want particle physics), pick up Montvay & Munster's [Quantum Fields on a Lattice](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-fields-on-a-lattice/4401A88CD232B0AEF1409BF6B260883A#).

Comment: I agree with this answer. I would also address the key issue of when to read all this. The OP seems to want to read things before getting into research papers in constructive QFT, in order to "get intuition about the subject". This would be a fatal mistake. One should read these references at the same time or even after, and not delay starting to get into constructive QFT proper. I gave specific suggestions in this related MO post  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397143/reading-list-recommendation-for-a-hep-ph-student-to-start-studying-qft-at-a-more

Comment: Yep.  It's worth saying explicitly:  Reading CQFT will also help the physics literature make sense.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful and elaborate answer! Since I originally made this post I went through parts of Griffiths' E&M book (skipping anything that was purely computational) and I have a better understanding of field theory now, though at an elementary level. I have also skipped around more of Peskin & Schroeder, but as you mentioned I have found this difficult as someone with only a math background. When you speak of avoiding particle physics, do you mean avoiding P&S-like books altogether?

Comment: I have always been a bit intimidated by statistical physics due to my lack of background in the subject, but your post has inspired me to give it a try. I have also been interested in learning about how lattice regularization is carried out but could not find an introduction for a novice such as myself, so those last two links are great! Thanks again!

Comment: @CBBAM yes,  Not just particle physics textbooks, but also the various QFT for Mathematicians books like Ticciati, Folland, and Talgrand that mirror them.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you, based on your comment and your linked post it seems I should start studying CQFT immediately and not just focus on the physics. Are there any beginner friendly resources you recommend that introduces some of the basics such as Wightman/Schwinger functions, the various axioms, their uses ...etc?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Also, in terms of math prerequisites, I have been having a hard time focusing on what to prepare for as CQFT seems to use a bit of everything. Do you have any suggestions on what I should focus on (e.g. more functional analysis, probability, differential geometry...etc)?

Comment: @user1504 I will take your advice. I was able to get through Folland's book and develop somewhat of an intuition for the subject, but the books written by and for physicists have been a different story. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @CBBAM: My advice is to forget about prerequisites, more functional analysis, probability, differential geometry, basics such as Wightman/Schwinger functions, etc., etc. This is all a distraction from CQFT. Instead, follow the link to the other MO post I mentioned, and read for example Guiliani-Mastropietro-Rychkov. Reading must be done in a focused tenacious way. If you don't know something they talk about, do a minimal "reverse tree exploration" in the literature, to learn about just that notion and then go back to their paper, and repeat.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you, I will start with their paper.